# How to solve Enum or Interface expected error

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
Public class Parent {

    int a, b;

    public void sum() {

        System.out.println(a + b);

    }

}

class Child extends Parent {

    public void mul() {

        System.out.println(a * b);

    }

}

class Inh1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Child c = new Child();

        c.a = 20;
        c.b = 20;

        c.sum();
        c.mul();

    }

}
```

This code works fine if  there is no "Public" written in front of child and parent class....the output would be....40 and 400 but once public is written ahead of class parent i get this error  **Inh1.java:1: class, interface, or enum expected** also same error comes if  i write Public ahead of Child class

My second doubt is when i write "Public"(capital P)  i get

```
Inh1.java:1: class, interface, or enum expected
```

but if i write "public"(small p) the error is

```
Inh1.java:1: class Parent is public, should be declared in a file named Parent.java
```

Please clarify these small doubt of mine i am new to programming, java and OOPS

Comment: this is a simple typographical error. Any IDE would correct this automatically, and that's reason enough to use them.

Comment: Also: java is case sensitive.

Comment: In Java each public class needs to be declared in a file with that name. So the public Parent class needs to be in Parent.java

Answer (score 1):

- there can be only one top-level public class in a file
- file should be named by that public class only
- it is public with small `p`

Comment: @soulcheck your comment is correct but not relevant. Inner classes are not in the scope of this question.

Comment: @soulcheck - I agree with alfasin. still i updated my answer for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

First, write public with lowercase `p`: `public` not `Public`

Second, only one (top-level) class can be public in a file (if the file is called Parent.java only class `Parent` can be public)